# OSM (XML) transformation

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xml-parsing, openstreetmap

I have been searching for a while for something that allows me a fast but efficient way to transform the xml that openstreetmaps (.osm) uses in order to create a better structure fitting my own purposes.

I thought and looked at different options such as XSLT, clean JavaScript or nodejs, but I'm not sure if this all fits my purposes.

An .osm file looks like this:

```
  <?xml version='1.0' standalone='no'?>
  <osm version='0.6' generator='xapi: OSM Extended API' 
   xmlns:xapi='http://www.informationfreeway.org/xapi/0.6'
   xapi:uri='/api/0.6/*[amenity=hotel]'
   xapi:planetDate='200803150826' 
   xapi:copyright='2008 OpenStreetMap contributors' 
   xapi:instance='zappy2'>
    <node id='218963' lat='52.5611324692581' lon='-1.79024812573334' timestamp='2006-03-22T16:47:48+00:00' version='1' changeset='2211'>
    </node>
    <node id='331193' lat='53.7091237972264' lon='-1.50282510180841' timestamp='2007-03-31T00:09:22+01:00' version='1' changeset='2211'>
      <tag k='amenity' v='hotel'/>
    </node>
    ... 
    <way id='4958218' timestamp='2007-07-25T01:55:35+01:00' version='1' changeset='2211'>
      <nd ref='218963'/>
      <nd ref='331193'/>
      ...
      <tag k='amenity' v='hotel'/>
      <tag k='building' v='hotel'/>
    </way>
    <relation id='123456' timestamp='2007-10-25T03:05:34Z' version='32' changeset='2211'>
      <member type='node' ref='331193' role=''/>
      <member type='node' ref='331194' role=''/>
      ...
      <tag k='amenity' v='hotel'/>
      <tag k='operator' v='Premier Inns'/>
      <tag k='type' v='operators'/>
    </relation>    
  </osm>
```

What I'd want to achieve is something like this:

```
<?xml version=‘1.0’ standalone=‘no’?>
<ways>
    <way>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>Name</name>
        <height>50m</height>
        <geocoord>51.00000, 12.00000</geocoord>
    </way>
<ways>
<relations>
    <relation>
        ..
    </relation>
</relations>
<nodes>
    <node>
    ..
    </node>
</nodes>
```

This is a very simplified version of the xml I had in mind.
But as you can see: I want to be able to extract the keys and values from tags but also from attributes from the data in osm. That means the data inside a `<node>` element (e.g. `<node id="123">`) as well as the subelement tag (e.g. `<node id=...><tag k="maxspeed" v="50"></node>`).

As there're lots of custom-created tags in osm as well, I would also require to parse the value of the "key" tag as I'd want to use that as well. (e.g. `<tag k="maxspeed" v="50">` maxspeed is a custom tag: it becomes `<maxspeed>50</maxspeed>`.

If you have any questions, don't hesitate to ask! I'd appreciate any input.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for general advice...  You're on the right track:  There's no better way to map from one XML structure to another than XSLT.

Comment: @kjhughes do you know if it's possible to extract the key values (as a string value) as well with xslt? I tried to search it but couldn't find a solution straight away.

Comment: Not sure what "key" refers to in the context of your input XML, but, yes, XSLT can access and transform string content in the input XML.  It'll be easier if you can use XSLT 2.0 (or above).

Comment: @kjhughes if you take a look at the first code strip, there's fe id='2189123'. What I wanted to know was if it's possible to extract "id" out of it as well as the value (2189123).

Comment: Yes, `id` is the attribute name, and you can access attribute names as well as attribute values.  It looks like your current concern is how to convert from attributes to elements.  XSLT can easily do this.  Search for "XSLT convert xml attributes to elements" for examples.